# Angular + JQuery JSPanel3 with content not working

Tags: jquery, angular

I have an Angular application that needs to use the jquery.jsPanel3 library to show some Pdfs. The problem is that I can open a jsPanel from my component and add some content to it but if the content has angular components, angular is not 'parsing/transforming' them. So my question is: how can I somehow trigger Angular to be aware of this new content? Here is the code that appends the content to the creates jspanel. pdf-viewer is the component that doesn't work.

`this.panel.content.append('<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc" [page]="1" [original-size]="false" style="display: block;"></pdf-viewer>');
}`

Comment: why are you using jquery append?

Comment: What should I use? The library doesn't have a wrapper for angular

Comment: Do you need to use the pdf-viewer component? Can't you use something like `panel.content.append('<object data="path/to/pdf" type="application/pdf"></object>');`